# after change email users can login before email verification in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito inside a mobile application to allow user to register and login. I'm using email as username. When the users signup, they receive the email with the verification link. If a user tries to login before clicking on the verification code an error is thrown. 
I implemented a function to allow the user to change the email. The function is working as expected: the user receive a code in the new email and, until the code is provided, inside the user pool the email is marked as not verified. The problem is that since the user use the email as a username, when changing email, the new email can be used for login even if not verified. Is this correct? The behaviour that I was expecting is that the user would be able to login only after the new email is verified.

Comment: This is my experience as well : / What approach did you take to save the users from locking themselves out?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but it has an answer nowadays. You can keep old values until the user verifies new ones.

Copying the answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794530/2727462

The Cognito team has finally fixed this, but you need to opt-in to the correct behavior.

From the developer guide:

> Amazon Cognito can also require that your user verifies the new value
> before Amazon Cognito updates the attribute. When you require that
> your users first verify the new value, they can use the original value
> for sign-in and to receive messages until they verify the new value.

To opt-in to this behavior, follow the steps on that page:

1. Sign in to the Amazon Cognito console. If prompted, enter your AWS
   credentials.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **User Pools**, and choose the user pool
   you want to edit.
3. In the **Sign-up experience** tab, choose **Edit** under **Attribute
   verification and user account confirmation**.
4. Choose **Keep original attribute value active when an update is
   pending**.
5. Under **Active attribute values when an update is pending**, choose the
   attributes that you want to require your users verify before Amazon
   Cognito updates the value.
6. Choose **Save changes**.

This will enable what should be the default behavior for user pools: The attribute will keep its old value until the user *actually verifies* the new value, at which point Cognito updates the value to the new one.