# AWS Cognito change email - require verification before update

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have user pool set up to use email as user identifier (also configured to require email verification). Every main action / flow (login, signup, change password, reset password) seem to work fine and as expected.

The one important thing which does not work as one would expect is **change email** flow:

When email change is requested, Cognito sends verification code to the new email as expected, **but** it also updates email to the new value **before** verification.

This causes a problem when f.ex.: new email was mistyped (so verification code never arrives) and user forgets its password. There seem to be no way to recover from it.
Am I missing, misconfigured or abuse something? There is a minimum user pool customisation I did (except case-insensitivity maybe).

What would be the reason that AWS allows to change email before verifying it (even if Cognito actually requires verification during signup, before account is created)?

Is there some user pool configuration settings (or lamba) or local SDK settings I am missing?

BTW: I am using `AWSMobileClient` from iOS SDK as a client but this probably does not matter(?).

Answer (score 6):

The Cognito team have finally fixed this, but you need to opt-in to the correct behavior.

From [the developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console_help_panel#user-pool-settings-verifications-verify-attribute-updates):

> Amazon Cognito can also require that your user verifies the new value before Amazon Cognito updates the attribute. When you require that your users first verify the new value, they can use the original value for sign-in and to receive messages until they verify the new value.

To opt-in to this behavior, follow the steps on that page:

1. Sign in to the [Amazon Cognito console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home). If prompted, enter your AWS
   credentials.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **User Pools**, and choose the user pool
   you want to edit.
3. In the **Sign-up experience** tab, choose **Edit** under **Attribute
   verification and user account confirmation**.
4. Choose **Keep original attribute value active when an update is
   pending**.
5. Under **Active attribute values when an update is pending**, choose the
   attributes that you want to require your users verify before Amazon
   Cognito updates the value.
6. Choose **Save changes**.

This will enable what should be the default behavior for user pools: The attribute will keep its old value until the user *actually verifies* the new value, at which point Cognito updates the value to the new one.

Comment: They still have not fixed their email templating issue. For example, `{username}` does not work with verification emails/texts.

Comment: @HafizTemuri I'm not sure what that has to do with the question or this answer.

Comment: just saying... because the above answer is still valid. It's best to do the verification flow yourself. Cognito is still full of bugs.

Comment: Also want to note here that the verification flow cannot be triggered by updating the login email with the admin API.  (ie: adminUpdateUserAttributes). Just in case anybody sees this answer when searching for how to do this in a way that is not initiated by the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Cognito, still waiting to be resolved for over 3 years. The solution many people find for this problem is to create their own verification-system.

For more detailed infos, see: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/987

Answer (score 0):

If you're here from an Amplify cli standpoint, you can implement what @Klaycon suggests using auth overrides.

`amplify override auth` - Select the Auth config you want to change

Update the override.ts file it generates to something like:

```js
import { AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyAuthCognitoStackTemplate) {
  resources.userPool.addPropertyOverride('UserAttributeUpdateSettings', {
    // Make it so updated attributes reflect in the user pool immediately
    // and don't require verification before actually updating.
    AttributesRequireVerificationBeforeUpdate: [],
  });
}
```

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-userattributeupdatesettings.html